# How to match a backslash with the like operator in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

How can I match a backslash with the like operator in Redshift?
I tried below, but they didn't work…

```
-- syntax error
select 'a\a' like '\';

-- false
select 'a\a' like '\\';

-- syntax error
select 'a\a' like '\\\';

-- syntax error
select 'a\a' like '\' escape '^';

-- syntax error
select 'a\a' like '^\' escape '^';
```

Answer (score 0):

Envelope it with `%`:

`select 'a\a' like '%\\%';`

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. But envelope with % didn't work.The following all returned `true true`. `select 'a\a' like '%\%', 'aa' like '%\%';`, `select 'a\a' like '%\%' escape '^', 'aa' like '%\%' escape '^';`

Comment: Use `%\\%` (double `\\`)

Comment: Thanks. Additionally, I needed to escape the input characters as well. `select 'a\\a' like '%\\%' escape '^', 'aa' like '%\\%' escape '^';` returned `true false`. (`select 'a\\a'` returned `a\a` and `select a\a` returned `aa`)